# CSS space between inside another flex element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, nav

I am trying to make simple nav-bar with logo, nav-links and button. and space everything evenly

I have wrapper around those 3 items and i apply `display:flex` and than inside  list i again apply `display:flex` but `justify-content` doesn't affect list items, they are merged together.

```css
.nav-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;

    background: rgba(245, 253, 255, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    backdrop-filter: blur(14px);
}
.nav--list{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="" class="logo">
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul class="nav--list">
            <li class="nav--list-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link boldy">Why Magic Massage</a></li>
            <li class="nav--list-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Features</a></li>
            <li class="nav--list-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Reviews</a></li>
            <li class="nav--list-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" class="order-now button">ORDER NOW</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `justify-content: space-between` does not mean "reserve space between the elements", but "if there is extra space, put it between elements". Due to the way the parent element is sized, there is no extra space to distribute. Use `padding` and `margin` instead. EDIT: TIL about `gap`; `gap` is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gap`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap

```css
.nav-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    background: rgba(245, 253, 255, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    backdrop-filter: blur(14px);
}
.nav--list{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 20px; /* add gap */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="" class="logo">
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul class="nav--list">
            <li class="nav--list-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link boldy">Why Magic Massage</a></li>
            <li class="nav--list-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Features</a></li>
            <li class="nav--list-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Reviews</a></li>
            <li class="nav--list-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" class="order-now button">ORDER NOW</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use css `gap` or `column-gap` property in your `nav--list` class:

```css
.nav-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    background: rgba(245, 253, 255, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    backdrop-filter: blur(14px);
}
.nav--list{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    column-gap: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="" class="logo">
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul class="nav--list">
            <li class="nav--list-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link boldy">Why Magic Massage</a></li>
            <li class="nav--list-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Features</a></li>
            <li class="nav--list-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Reviews</a></li>
            <li class="nav--list-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" class="order-now button">ORDER NOW</a>
</div>
```